# How to make and run servlet with eclipse kepler and apache 7

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am making this new servlet:

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Hello
 */
public class Hello extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Hello()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("It works");
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

and this is my web.xml in WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

display-name and welcome-file-list tags are generated automatically when I created the Dynamic web project. The servlet and servlet-mapping is written by me. When I run the project with appache 7 it says HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your servlet lives under /FirstServlet/Hello

Comment: yes you are right with package it runs but only when I pres run on java file, but if I run the whole project it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

1) You probably lack all of the welcome files you've listed. A 404 is what should happen when none are present.

2) Your servlet mapping is broken.  The servlet-class element requires a fully qualified class name, which would be `Servlets.Hello` rather than just `Hello`. When mapped correctly,  `/FirstServlet/hello` will get to your servlet, matching the mapped URI, then finding the registered servlet by name, and finally to the fully qualified class that should be executed.

Comment: ok I have removed display-name and welcome-file-list from web.xml also change the class element with Servlets.Hello and now if I run the project it says "HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/" and if I run the java file it works. I want to make it run when I run the project.

Comment: @user3430773 Did you try my comment on you answer and point 2 from @nitind?